# AlarmManager.setRepeating stops working after a while

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Below is my code, it works great for the first 7 or so days but after that it just stops. I am not sure why?

I am having much the same problem as this person:
[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2ardur/alarmmanager_stops_firing_after_a_while/)

Any help will be appreciated:)

```
Intent _intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, _intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
    // every 24 hours (daily) at the time set
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * minTime * MainSetTimeInt, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: What's your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Currently Android API 28 (16-28)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem. I target API 33. (it used to work fine when I targeted API 30)

Comment: Yes @Youb. You can see all the changes and how I used it [here].(https://github.com/BibleNotify/BibleNotify)